# Failure in executeAsync with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, mozilla

I've created this code, to send some insert statements to a SQLite DB:

> ```
>       new_db.executeAsync(stmts,stmts.length, {
>             handleResult: function(aResultSet) {
>               Firebug.Console.log("insert_data -> handleResult (" + aResultSet + ")");
>             },
>             handleError: function(aError) {
>               Firebug.Console.log("insert_data -> handleError (" + aError.result + "," + aError.message + ")");
>             },
>             handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
>                 Firebug.Console.log("insert_data -> completed");
>                 Firebug.Console.log(aReason);
>             }   
>         });
> ```

In the output, I find:

`insert_data -> completed`

`65535`

I cannot figure what this 65535 means. This shouldn't be an error (otherwise I would have insert_data -> handleError), but why the returned value isn't zero? Is there a way to obtain a description of the code?

In any case, no value is being inserted by my statements, so it should be a failure error code.

Thanks,

Livio

Answer (score 0):

I've found the explanation... the stmts array was empty (stmts.length=0). That's the meaning of this strange return code... that should be somehow documented, in my opinion.